# How do I display the current year in roman numerals?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, oracle10g

I'm trying to display the current year as roman numerals.  I tried nesting a to_char in another to_char as an argument, but no luck.  if to_char(current_date, 'year') returns a 2020, why cant I just use that another to_char?

```
 select current_date, 
       to_char(current_date, 'RM') AS "Month",
       to_char(to_char(current_date, 'year'), 'rn') AS "year"
       
from dual;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to display the current year as roman numerals.

You can extract the year from the date, then use `to_char()` to convert that number to its roman representation:

```
select to_char(extract(year from current_date), 'FMRM') roman_year from dual;

| ROMAN_YEAR |
| :--------- |
| MMXX       |
```

Modifier `FM` removes leading spaces that the resulting string would otherwise contain.